# Class is returning two different object

Tags: python, django

I am trying to apply the Singleton design pattern in the below code

```
class SMSMgr( object ):
    _instance = None
    def __init__(self):
            self._allsp = []
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(SMSMgr, cls).__new__(
                                cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    def loadsettings(self):
        get_all_sp = ServiceProvider.objects.filter(status = False)
        for obj in get_all_sp:
            cla = obj.class_Name
            a=globals()[str(obj.class_Name)](obj.userName,obj.password,obj.sendingurl)
            self._allsp.append(a)
            #print self._allsp
    def send(self):
        print "+++++++++++++++++++== Global send "


if __name__ == "__main__":

    b = SMSMgr()
    b.loadsettings()
    print b._allsp
    print "b end -------------------"
    c = SMSMgr()
    c.loadsettings()
    print c._allsp
    print "c end -------------------"
```

According to singleton b object should be same as c object .
But when i am running this above code i am getting the different objects for `b` and `c` 
Please suggest me how can i do this as a Singleton.

Comment: The Singleton pattern in this form is a borrowing from Java, and I don't understand why people are so attached to it.  You are working hard to make a class that lies:  it looks to the caller like they are making a new instance, and you are manipulating things behind the scenes so that they are not.

Why not just give them a single instance to use?  Or a factory function that produces the instance to use?  This is confusing in implementation, and confusing to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem here is that there is no sentinel for your `__init__`, so even though each instantiation returns the same object, `__init__` is being rerun each time as well.  You could try something like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_allsp'):
        self._allsp = []
```

Though for a more robust solution, you probably want something more like:

```
def __init__(self):
    if not hasattr(self.__class__, 'inited'):
        self._allsp = []
        self.__class__.inited = True
```

Just be aware that this is not thread safe unless you wrap the init functionality in a lock of some sort.

As @mgilson eludes to in his answer though, if you are trying to create a singleton in Python, you probably should just be using class attributes instead of instance attributes, and looking at whether it even makes sense for the class to be completely separate to begin with, or to fold it in to some other, non-singleton class.  There's also a pattern, the [borg pattern](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531/), that is frequently mentioned when singetons and Python are brought up in the same paragraph.

Comment: please ue some program so that i can figure out

Comment: thanks it works  one more thing how can i call it on different file like oo = SMSMgr()
print oo._allsp   it is returning empty list ?

Answer (score 2):

Your singleton pattern looks like it should work to me.  Is is possible that since `__init__` is being called both times, when you create a new instance, `self._allsp` gets reset making it appear that you have a new instance?

You can check to see if they are actually the same instance by putting:

```
print b is c
```

at the end of your script.  (It'll print `True` if they're the same)

The simplest fix that I can think of is to make `_allsp` a class attribute and remove it from `__init__`.  e.g.

```
class SMSMgr( object ):
    _instance = None
    _allsp = []
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

---

Here is some tested code which creates a singleton as expected as I described above:

```
class SMSMgr( object ):
    _instance = None
    _allsp = []
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(SMSMgr, cls).__new__(
                                cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    def foo(self,arg):
        self._allsp.append(arg)

    def bar(self):
        print self._allsp

a = SMSMgr()
a.foo(1)
b = SMSMgr()
b.foo(2)
a.bar()
b.bar()
print a is b
```

Comment: @masterofdestiny -- did you try it?  I don't think it will :-)

Comment: one more thing how to import it on other file oo = SMSMgr() print  oo._allsp  is returning empty list ?

Comment: @masterofdestiny -- I think we'd need to see more code before we could figure that one out.  Maybe post it as a separate question (with the code from the relevant files and a link to this one for some context?)